# Align tooltip with mouse move when hovering over segments in stacked bar plot [Qlik Sense Extension]

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, qliksense

I am using Qlik Sense Cloud and I have successfully created a stacked bar plot using d3.js v4 framework. The chart looks like:

[image]

As you can notice the tooltip is not correctly placed on the blue segment of USA (its wrong placed on white space above Japan-Nordic). In case you want to test the code for yourself I would suggest to use the [zip folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n87nlfDhgeiHl-MDAHM-NcMRyMWZnczW/view?usp=sharing) from here and upload it to a Qlik Sense version you work. I have also included a qvf file. I know for sure that my problem lies in the Qlik Sense window because testing the same code in the below attached jsfiddle window worked for me. But it doesn't work on Qlik Sense as expected.

I have also uploaded a [question](https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/Align-tooltip-on-mousemove-in-d3-js-v4-stacked-bar-chart/m-p/1799168#M183073) in Qlik Sense community but I had no answer yet.

Specifically I use the following code to place my tooltip:

````
```javascript
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
var xPosition = d3.event.pageX;
var yPosition = d3.event.pageY;

toolTip.style("left", xPosition + 10 + "px");
toolTip.style("top", yPosition - 25 + "px");
toolTip.style("position", "absolute");
toolTip.style("display", "inline-block");
tooltip.html(...)
}
```
````

```js
data=[{dValues: "Germany", m1Values: 3323936.920000017, m2Values: 1469934.4999999946},
{dValues: "Japan", m1Values: 11847615.030000022, m2Values: 4860290.499999991},
{dValues: "Nordic", m1Values: 10382965.910000034, m2Values: 4289934.389999997},
{dValues: "Spain", m1Values: 3449601.7199999965, m2Values: 1594701.149999997},
{dValues: "UK", m1Values: 28157182.22999989, m2Values: 12590207.999999987},
{dValues: "USA", m1Values: 47691372.99999974, m2Values: 18448120.5719999}]

var quarters = data.map(function(d) { return d.dValues; })
//console.log('Quarters: ', quarters);

var layers = d3.stack().keys(["m1Values", "m2Values", "m3Values"]).order(d3.stackOrderNone).offset(d3.stackOffsetNone)(data);
//console.log('Layers: ', layers);

var max = d3.max(layers[layers.length-1], function(d) { return d[1]; });

// helper Function to round the displayed numbers
var roundNumber = function roundNumber(num, noPrecision){
//check if the string passed is number or contains formatting like 13%
if (/^[0-9.]+$/.test(num)) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num);
if (num >= 1000 && num < 1000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'K'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000 && num < 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'M'; // Add the abbreviation
} else if (num >= 1000000000) {
num = !noPrecision ? parseFloat(num / 1000000000).toFixed(2) : Math.round(num / 1000000000);
if (/\.00$/.test(num)) {
num = num.replace(/\.00$/, ''); // Remove .00
}
num += 'T'; // Add the abbreviation
}
}
return num;
};

// Step 1: set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60 }; //adjust left margin to show how y-axis +20 in bottom and left for X,Y axis titles
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Step 2: set the ranges for x, y axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
.range([0, width])
.padding(0.3) //padding will help 

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([height, 0]);

color = null;
color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888"]);

//Step 4: Set color domains
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "dValues"; }));

//Step 5: Create the dataset as needed for the stacked barchart
data.forEach(function(d) {
var y0 = 0;
d.values = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
d.total = d.values[d.values.length - 1].y1;
});

//step 6: Set rest domains
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
x.domain(quarters);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the svg chart
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Create Parent Group layering
svg.append("g").attr("id", "grid");

//Add x axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")));

//toolTip
var toolTip = d3.select("body").append("div")
.attr("class", "toolTip")
.html("toolTip")
.style("display", "none");

var project_stackedbar = svg.selectAll(".project_stackedbar")
.data(data.reverse())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "g")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x(d.dValues))  + ",0)"; });

var bar_environment = project_stackedbar.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d.values; })
.enter();
bar_environment.append("rect")
.attr("class", "rect-svg")
.attr("x",  d => x(d.dValues))
.attr("y", function(d) {
return y(d.y1);
})
.attr("width", x.bandwidth() - 1)
.attr("height", function(d){
return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
})
.style("fill", function(d) {
return color(d.name);
});

bar_environment.append("text")
.attr("class", "text-svg")
.attr("y", function(d) {
return y(d.y1)+(y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))/2;
})
.attr("x", function(d){
return x.bandwidth()/2;
})
.attr("text-anchor","middle")
.attr("font-size","12px")
.attr("font-family","Helvetica")
.style("fill", "#000000")
.text(function(d) {
return roundNumber(d.y1 - d.y0);
});

project_stackedbar.on("mouseover", function() { toolTip.style("display", null); })
.on("mouseout", function() { toolTip.style("display", "none"); })
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
// var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0];
// var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1];
var xPosition = d3.event.pageX;
var yPosition = d3.event.pageY;
// toolTip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
toolTip.style("left", xPosition + 10 + "px");
toolTip.style("top", yPosition - 25 + "px");
toolTip.style("position", "absolute");
toolTip.style("display", "inline-block");
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
l = elements.length
l = l-1
element = elements[l].__data__
value = element.y1 - element.y0
if(element.name === "m1Values"){
toolTip.html("Region" + ": " + (d.dValues) +
"<br>"+ "Sum(Sales)" + ": " + roundNumber(value));
} else if(element.name ==="m2Values"){
toolTip.html("Region" + ": " + (d.dValues) +
"<br>"+ "Sum(Margin)" + ": " + roundNumber(value));
}else{
toolTip.html("Region" + ": " + (d.dValues) +
"<br>"+ "Sum(GrossSales)" + ": " + roundNumber(value));
}
});

var totalLabels = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'totals');
totalLabels.selectAll('.total')
.data(data)
.enter().append('text')
.attr('class', 'total')
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.dValues) + x.bandwidth()/2; })
.attr("y", function(d) {
// Retrieve the horizontal coordinates based on total (stored as d.value)
// Add pixel offset so labels don't stick to end of stacked bars
return y(d.total) - 5;  })
.attr("text-anchor","middle")
.attr("font-size","12px")
.attr("font-family","Helvetica")
.style("fill", "#000000")
.text(function(d) {
// Inject total as text content (stored as d.value)
return roundNumber(d.total);
});

var legend = svg.append("g")
.attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
.attr("font-size", 10)
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.selectAll("g")
.data(["Sum(Sales)", "Sum(Margin)", "Sum(GrossSales)"])
.enter().append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", width - 19)
.attr("width", 19)
.attr("height", 19)
.attr("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", width - 24)
.attr("y", 9.5)
.attr("dy", "0.32em")
.text(function(d) { return d; });

console.log("Stacked BarChart completed");
```

```css
/* .bar {
fill: steelblue; Not needed anymore after adding the color picker
} */

div.toolTip{
position: absolute; /*we need the tooltip to follow the mouse on the screen */
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.9;
border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
padding: 10px;
}
.gridlines line {
stroke: lightgrey;
stroke-opacity: 0.7;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.gridlines path {
stroke-width: 0;
}
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: Hello to the community members. Is this question relevant here? Or should I post it somewhere else were Qlik members have access. It's been a while since I posted this question but didn't receive any answer yet. Best regards.